# ReactJS passing props from root to child

Tags: reactjs

I have an app purely built on react. As my app and component base continues to grow. I see that I have to pass down more and more props down from the main root component child(stateless) components. And sometimes this passing down is quite deep atleast 3-4 levels deep.

What is a good way to solve this issue in React?

Comment: Where do you have all your application state ? in the root component ?

Comment: I think you are looking for design patterns. I highly recommend you to go through Redux once you master react basics. Also refer [Flux vs Redux](https://edgecoders.com/the-difference-between-flux-and-redux-71d31b118c1), and also  [why redux](http://almerosteyn.com/2016/08/redux-explained-again)

Comment: [Context provides a way to pass data through the component tree without having to pass props down manually at every level.](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

Comment: @Håken also from that very same page, "Don’t use context just to avoid passing props a few levels down. Stick to cases where the same data needs to be accessed in many components at multiple levels."

Comment: Yes. There are pros and cons of the context api. If you need to pass data down multiple levels, maybe you should simplify it? Could the consumers be direct children of the root component? The intermediate components could simply take a `{children}` prop. Another option is to just pass every prop down to child components `const Foo = ({title, ...props}) => <div><h1>{title}</h1><Bar {...props} /></div>`. Or use redux. There's lots of ways to solve this.

Comment: the good way for passing props to a 4 lvl deep is Redux, nor more to say.

Answer (score 2):

This is one of the motivations behind centralised state management using e.g. [Redux](https://redux.js.org/), and "connected" components whose props can include those in the global store.

Instead of passing the props down the component hierarchy, changes are made to the global state in the store and the components which use the data have their props updated.

Comment: Use MobX store or Redux and set state there rather than passing down the props as this can in one central location. Can be a bit difficult to track though if code not organized properly.

Answer (score 0):

It depends which version react are you using.
If latests try context: https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html or
simple state manager like Redux, Mobx etc.

Comment: Quoting that page you linked to: "Don’t use context just to avoid passing props a few levels down. Stick to cases where the same data needs to be accessed in many components at multiple levels."